# Is there an easier way to solve this logarithmic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2\log _{ 8 }{ x } =\log _{ 2 }{ x-1 } $$

Steps I took:

$$\frac { \log _{ 2 }{ x^{ 2 } }  }{ \log _{ 2 }{ 8 }  } =\log _{ 2 }{ x-1 } $$

$$\frac { \log _{ 2 }{ x^{ 2 } }  }{ 3 } =\log _{ 2 }{ x-1 } $$

$$\log _{ 2 }{ x^{ 2 } } =3\log _{ 2 }{ x-1 } $$

$$2\log _{ 2 }{ x } =3\log _{ 2 }{ x-1 } $$

$$\log _{ 2 }{ x } =\frac { 3 }{ 2 } \log _{ 2 }{ x-1 } $$

$$\log _{ 2 }{ x } =\log _{ 2 }{ (x-1)^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } } $$

This method seems to be very inefficient and I don't know how I would go from here. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Hints only please. No actual solution.

Comment: Is that $-1+\log_2x$ or $\log_2(x-1)$?  Because it looks like the first, but you treat it like the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice,  $\ \ \large \log_{a^n}(b)=\frac{1}{n}\log_a(b)$

Now, we have $$2\log_8x=\log_2x-1$$
$$2\log_{2^3}x=\log_2x-1$$
$$\frac{2}{3}\log_{2}x=\log_2x-1$$ $$\frac{1}{3}\log_{2}x=1$$
$$\log_2x=3\implies x=2^3=\color{red}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using a change of base: $$\log_b a = \frac{\log_n a}{\log_n b}$$

Change $\log_8 x^2$ base to 2: $$\log_8 x^2 = \frac{\log_2 x^2}{\log_2 8} = \frac{2\log_2 x}{3} $$

Let $\log_2 x = a$

$$ \frac{2a}{3}= a-1 \ \implies \ a=3$$

$$\log_2 x = 3\ \implies \ x=2^3 = 8$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Remember that 
$$
\log_b{b} = 1
$$
so: $1=\log_2 2$
and

$$
  \log_2{a} - \log_2{b} = {\log_2{a} \over \log_2{b}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$2\log_{8}x=\log_{2}x-1$

$2\log_{2}x=3\log_{2}x-3$ based on $\log_{8}x=\frac{\log_{2}x}{\log_{2}8}=\frac{\log_{2}x}{3}$

$3=\log_{2}x$

$8=2^{3}=x$

Answer (score -1):

$\log_a(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$

$2\log_8(x)=\log_2(x)-1$

$2\frac{\ln(x)}{3\ln(2)}=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}-1$

$-\frac{\ln(x)}{3\ln(2)}=-1$

$\frac{1}{3}\log_2(x)=1$

$\log_2(x)=3$

$x=8$